# Why am I getting an Invalid Hook Call Error? Can't seem to fix problem

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, reactjs

Yes I have already installed the Icons and Core folders for the icons in case you're wondering
This is the code:

import React from 'react'
import './Header.css'
import SearchIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Search";

function Header() {
return (

```
   <div className='header__center'>
   <input type="text"/>
   <SearchIcon />

   
   </div>

    </div>
)
```

}

export default Header

Comment: There's no hooks in that code. And I'm pretty sure MUI icons don't have any hooks in their source code either, they're just SVGs. Please include the actual error message and the specific line where the error is getting thrown

Comment: Error Message: 
Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
▶ 31 stack frames were collapsed.

Comment: It didn't start doing that until I added the "Import from SearchIcon" Line

Comment: Please note that react >= 16.8.0 and react-dom >= 16.8.0 are peer dependencies.  from their website, you may need to check react and react-dom versions

Comment: I am on the latest version and everything but I still can't seem to figure it out.